# Nestjs Typeorm ManyToOne relationship

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

> ERROR [ExceptionHandler] column "departmentId" is in a primary key

This is the code:

```
@ManyToOne(() => Department, {
    nullable: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    cascade: true,
})  
@JoinColumn()
department: Department;
```

If I use this,

```
@ManyToOne(() => Department, {
        nullable: true,
        primary: true,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        cascade: true,
    })         

    @JoinColumn()
    department: Department;
```

I get the error :

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(typeFunctionOrTarget: string | ((type?: any) => ObjectType<Department>), options?: RelationOptions): PropertyDecorator', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ nullable: true; primary: boolean; onDelete: "CASCADE"; cascade: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RelationOptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'primary' does not exist in type 'RelationOptions'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(typeFunctionOrTarget: string | ((type?: any) => ObjectType<Department>), inverseSide?: string | ((object: Department) => any), options?: RelationOptions): PropertyDecorator', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ nullable: boolean; primary: boolean; onDelete: string; cascade: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | ((object: Department) => any)'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'nullable' does not exist in type '(object: Department) => any'.ts(2769)
```